# some selects with the same id ,its correct or it's a mistake

Tags: html

I'm dealing with some legacy code and I've found that

```
<div class="form-group form-widget form-widget-children" data-widget-type="widget_options_list" data-role="prototype" data-action-event="change">
    <h3>texto:</h3>

    <select id="sid_15-cqid_111" class="form-control auto-width" name="sid_15-cqid_111[]" >
        <option value="-1" selected>Selecciona una opción.</option>
        <option value="1274" >A</option>
        <option value="1275" >B</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-widget form-widget-children" data-widget-type="widget_options_list" data-role="clone" data-action-event="change"                                >
    <h3>#1.-text:</h3>

    <select id="sid_15-cqid_111" class="form-control auto-width" name="sid_15-cqid_111[]" >
        <option value="-1" >Selecciona una opción.</option>
        <option value="1274" selected>A</option>
        <option value="1275" >B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The selects has the same id , and the name it's an array.Id is an unique identifier  it's a mistake or  can be correct because  the name It's an array?

Comment: it can have a glitch because of that

Comment: Id is unique identifier, you can use the same class instead.